# Creating a loop to subset data groups, run a t.test, and write results to a new df of ALL t.tests by Region and timestep

Tags: r, loops, subset, t.test

I have a large dataset and I am looking to run t.tests on sub-groupings of my data.
I have had success with t.test on a broad scale:

```
t.test(Measurement~Group, data=df, paired="FALSE")
```

*But* I need to break my data down first by region, and then by time series, and *then* run a t.test on the pre and post measurement.
(In my actual dataset, I have 12 Regions and 24 time series.. so to do it manually would be 288 tests!)

I'm sure there is a relatively simple loop or something I can apply but I am really struggling as a new coder.

Thanks so much in advance for any help!!

Here is some sample data:

```
Region <- c("A","A","B","B","C","C", "D", "D", "E","E")
TimeSeries<- c("1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2")
Measurement <- c("0.1", "9.7", "8.3", "2.0", "0.3", "1.2", "4.4", "6.9", "5.3","3.2")
Group<- c("Pre", "Post","Pre", "Post","Pre", "Post","Pre", "Post","Pre", "Post")

df <- data.frame(Region,TimeSeries,Measurement,Group)
```

I tried this:

```
df_list <- split(df, as.factor(df$Region))
```

.. and now I have a list, but not sure how to work with that in terms of further splitting by time series and then running the t.tests and having results in a new dataframe.

Ideal outcome would be analyzing my data and having a table like this:

Region  TimeSeries  p-value  (other columns that come as test results..)

```
  A         1          0.7      .....
  A         2          0.002    .....
```

... and so on with a result for each region and timestep.